# how can I set deafult current user in a Sharepoint list new form column?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How can I set a current logged in user in a field of sharepoint new item form out of the box.
using column formatting, list formatting.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please use the below JSON:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@me"
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

- [@me is not retrieving the current user's email. #6516](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6516)

Comment: It is adding my email ID even when other user is sumbitting the form, do we have something like @CurrentUser in column formatting?